# why 'LDR' cannot replace with 'B'?

Tags: assembly, arm

I have a program(arm) and some instructions in there(disas by IDA):

```
.plt:000083F0   ADRL   R12, 0x83F8
.plt:000083F8   LDR    PC, [R12,#(off_90D8 - 0x83F8)]! ; sub_83D0
```

The addr 0x90D8 stores 0x83D0:

```
000090D8  D0 83 00 00
```

So, after ldr, the pc is 0x83D0 and will exec the inst in 0x83D0, isn't?

Here I want to jmp to 0x83D0 directly and not use 09D8, I modify the binary machine code and reload it by IDA:

```
.plt:000083F0   B   sub_83D0
```

IDA shows that it will jmp to 0x83D0, so I think the modify is valid.
However, the program failed to run after modify.
Is there any wrong with my modify and how to achieve my target? Please help me...

I put some more disas here:
**SRC**

```
.plt:000083E4
.plt:000083E4 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.plt:000083E4
.plt:000083E4 ; Attributes: thunk
.plt:000083E4
.plt:000083E4 sub_83E4                                ; CODE XREF: .text:00008410j
.plt:000083E4                 ADRL            R12, 0x83EC
.plt:000083EC                 LDR             PC, [R12,#(off_90D4 - 0x83EC)]! ; sub_83D0
.plt:000083EC ; End of function sub_83E4
.plt:000083EC
.plt:000083F0
.plt:000083F0 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.plt:000083F0
.plt:000083F0 ; Attributes: thunk
.plt:000083F0
.plt:000083F0 sub_83F0                                ; CODE XREF: sub_8430+6p
.plt:000083F0                                         ; sub_8430+Ep ...
.plt:000083F0                 ADRL            R12, 0x83F8
.plt:000083F8                 LDR             PC, [R12,#(off_90D8 - 0x83F8)]! ; sub_83D0
.plt:000083F8 ; End of function sub_83F0
.plt:000083F8
.plt:000083F8 ; .plt          ends
.plt:000083F8
```

**modified**

```
.plt:000083E4
.plt:000083E4 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.plt:000083E4
.plt:000083E4 ; Attributes: thunk
.plt:000083E4
.plt:000083E4 sub_83E4                                ; CODE XREF: .text:00008410j
.plt:000083E4                 ADRL            R12, 0x83EC
.plt:000083EC                 LDR             PC, [R12,#(off_90D4 - 0x83EC)]! ; sub_83D0
.plt:000083EC ; End of function sub_83E4
.plt:000083EC
.plt:000083F0
.plt:000083F0 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.plt:000083F0
.plt:000083F0
.plt:000083F0 sub_83F0                                ; CODE XREF: sub_8430+6p
.plt:000083F0                                         ; sub_8430+Ep ...
.plt:000083F0                 ADRL            R12, loc_83F8
.plt:000083F8
.plt:000083F8 loc_83F8                                ; DATA XREF: sub_83F0o
.plt:000083F8                 B               sub_83D0
.plt:000083F8 ; End of function sub_83F0
.plt:000083F8
.plt:000083F8 ; .plt          ends
.plt:000083F8
```

And in 0x90D4:

```
000090D4  D0 83 00 00 D0 83 00 00
```

Comment: Maybe there are dependencies to the value of `R12` elsewhere in the code? Note that the `LDR` instruction specifies write-back to the base register (`R12`).

Comment: please provide disassembly for these examples.

Comment: I save R12 just now(see above) but it's still failed to run. Maybe need BL or BX?

Comment: Artless Noise makes an important point, but I worry about something else - you are modifying the plt, and you are doing it based on contents of memory apparently *before the the runtime linker has done its work*.  Especially as your dump @ 90D4 seems to indicate that the same address is showing up multiple times, I have a suspicion that this address leads to having the runtime linker resolve a yet-unresolved symbol.  By hard patching in a branch there, you may never use the result which the runtime linker finds, but instead always go to the linker.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I do it in x86 successfully, but has some troubles in arm. I hate arm...

Answer (score 2):

The instruction `B   sub_83D0` is **PC** relative.  The instruction sequence,

```
.plt:000083F0   ADRL   R12, 0x83F8
.plt:000083F8   LDR    PC, [R12,#(off_90D8 - 0x83F8)]! ; sub_83D0

000090D8:  D0 83 00 00
```

Is PC relative, but it jumps to an **absolute** address.  Your assumption is that the **link** address is the **runtime** address.  This is not always true, especially in *bootstrap* code which may *relocate* or enable an *MMU*.

The sequence above can run from any address and will transfer control to the absolute *0x83d0*, the *branch* variant only changes the `PC` by adding an offset.  Ie,

```
PC = PC + (SignExtend) (immediate << 2);
```

An equivalent would be `mov pc, #0x83D0`, but this will not fit the `mov` immediates limitation of an *8bit* rotated by a multiple of 2.  You could try,

```
mov r12, #0x8300
orr pc, r12, #0xd0
```

but the code that is transferred to may also need the `r12` value set to the older *runtime* address.

Comment: You mean that the src inst will jmp to the absolute 0x83d0, but my modify is not sure?

Comment: Right, the `b` is **NOT** absolute.  The original is (and sets `r12` as Chris notes); that maybe important as well.

Comment: So, is there has any method can jmp to the absolute 0x83d0 directly and do not use 90D8?

Comment: Yes, that is the end part of my answer, but it does not set `R12` to 0x90D8 (or rather the old *runtime* location), but to only 0x8300.

Comment: Thank you. Although the problem has not been solved yet, your suggestion lets me learn more knowledge about arm.