# Using ASM command in C

Tags: c, assembly, arm, clang

I have a small question about using ASM in c. I want to execute the instruction:

```
LDR PC,=0x123456
```

This gives me the error "unexpected token in operand".

```
asm("LDR PC,=0x123456");
```

This gives "invalid constraint".

```
asm("LDR PC," : "m" (0x123456));
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Which C compiler are we talking about here?

Comment: inline assembly is not supported on all compilers - e.g. sun sparc - and, if it is, is compiler-specific

Comment: By invalid `constrant` you mean `constraint` right?

Comment: why not just branch to that address in C and not mess with asm?

Comment: or do it in real asm and not inline? you probably want to use bx not ldr anyway so a copy to r0 then bx r0 doesnt cost you really any more by using asm vs inline.

Comment: I want to load pc to a different position (code cave). I am using clang to compile it by the way

Comment: Why not just invoke the code if that is a routine or perform a jump?

Comment: Some reading: [ldr vs mov](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046686/ldr-vs-mov-arm-assembly), [replace ldr with b](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428025/why-ldr-cannot-replace-with-b), [Placing address in a register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774581/placing-the-address-a-register-is-pointing-at-in-to-a-register), [LDR literal pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680185/ldr-literal-pool-arm), etc.  [ARM+ldr+equals](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[arm]+ldr+%3D)

Answer (score 2):

You are using this:

```
asm("LDR PC,=0x123456");
```

This is not a standard ARM assembly instruction, but a pseudo-instruction provided as a compiler extension. This pseudo-instruction is converted to other assembly instructions when you compile it. It seems clang doesn't support this compiler extension (see this [thread](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2013-March/060188.html)). You should do the conversion to assembly instructions yourself, see the ARM documentation for how the [LDR pseudo-instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/Chdcegci.html) is converted.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve the effect you want in plain C:

```
((void (*)(void))0x123456)();
```

or if you prefer more verbose:

```
typedef void FN(void);
((FN*)0x123456)();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Étienne. I tried you code with mi Google toolchain. It's working fine.

I think you should read the manual how the compiler changes the directive to instructions (normally two *mov* instructions).